# Change font in UITextInput

Tags: ios, swift, uitextinput

I'm trying to develop a keyboard and it should use a different font then the default one. Here's the line:

```
   override func textDidChange(textInput: UITextInput?) {

    textInput.font = UIFont(name: "font name", size: 30)

}
```

But it doesn't work.... How can I fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: which font you are using ?

Comment: If this were possible I would use a .ttf font I've created. It already works in Swift, but I'm not able the tell the program I want to change the font of the UITextInput.... The problem isn't the font I use, but the line textInput.font is not correct, and throws back an error. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps to use custom Fonts

1. Drag and drop your font into Xcode
2. Choose options for adding these files:
      Copy items if needed
      Create groups
      Add to targets:(your app name)
3. In your Info.plist file add a key named: Fonts provided by application, which is an array
4. Customize your font:

   ```
    myUILabel.text = "demoText"
    myUILabel.font = UIFont(name: "myCustomFont.ttf", size: 25)
   ```

Comment: Even adding the .ttf in the line still doesn't work: it says: "Value of type 'UITextInput?' has no member 'font'"

Comment: what is it ? please make sure each and every steps you have to follow

Comment: I've done every step you suggested, but it doesn't work

Comment: But the problem is that I'm coding for a custom keyboard that should have an output with a font I want to use, and I'm not able to change the font of my output.

Comment: ouch! that's not good to ear... Thanks. (Maybe do you have any suggestion of how to use a custom font?)

Comment: It seems that the problem isn't the font settings: for example I am able to use the font in the same KeyBoardViewController.swift for the buttons of the keyboard. But when I try to use the font for the text that has been written by the user I can't do it without errors.

Comment: @LordNexprex any update for custom font with custom keyboard approach ...had u done …thanks